# How can I display a character count / word count for Redactor rich text / html editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, redactor

I have just replaced CKEditor (which came with a wealth of mysterious problems relating to AJAX updates to the DOM) with the excellent [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor). We previously used a CKEditor plugin to give us a character count for the rich text editor. How can I achieve the same thing with Redactor? There's nothing built in and no "plugin" architecture to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had a stab at this. I'm sure there will be better ways of achieving the same thing, but I'll post it in case it's a good start for someone else in the same fix.

The following code adds a rich text editor to any textarea fields that have the class "richText", and further adds a character count ONLY if the maxlength attribute is used on the textarea, eg

```
<textarea class="richText" maxlength="100"></textarea>
```

Here I've included CSS right in the javascript. In reality I'd take this out into a separate css file.

```
var initRichText = function () {
    $("textarea.richText").redactor({
        buttons: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist'],
        keyupCallback: function (obj, event) {
            var max = obj.$el.getEditor().next().attr("maxlength");
            if (typeof max !== "undefined") {
                var current = obj.$el.getCode().length;
                var $box = obj.$el.closest(".redactor_box");
                var $indicator = $(".indicator", $box);
                if ($indicator.size() === 0) {
                    $box.append($("<div class='indicator' style='position:absolute;z-index:30;top:7px;right:7px;'><span class='current'>" + current + "</span> of <span class='max'>" + max + "</span> characters remaining</div>"));
                } else {
                    $(".current", $indicator).text(current);
                    $(".max", $indicator).text(max);
                }
                if (current >= max) {
                    $box.css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
                    $indicator.css("color", "#ff0000");
                } else {
                    $box.css("border", "1px solid #DDDDDD");
                    $indicator.css("color", "#000000");
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
$(function(){
    initRichText();
});
```

EDIT: as MForMarlon says, redactor.js has changed since we wrote this code. By a very strange coincidence we were working on this TODAY, having not touched it for more than a year! Weird. Anyway, here's the latest version that works with Redactor v9.2.5. Note that we're now using initCallback to apply the character counter when the rich text editor first loads, instead of when the user starts typing. We're also using changeCallback instead of keyupCallback because we've added a "paste as plain text" modal (see [redactor.js pastePlainText - but need button to paste html instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24265321/136416)), and we want to react to content pasted in via that as well as typed in.

```
$(".richText").redactor({
    shortcuts: false,
    buttons: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', '|', 'html', 'pasteAsPlainText'],
    plugins: ['pasteAsPlainText'],
    initCallback: function (event) {
        var max = this.$editor.next().attr("maxlength");
        if (typeof max !== "undefined" && max > 0) {
            var html = this.get();
            var current = html.length;
            var remaining = max - current;
            this.$box.append($("<div class='indicator' style='position:absolute;z-index:30;top:7px;right:7px;'><span class='current'>" + remaining + "</span> of <span class='max'>" + max + "</span> characters remaining</div>"));
        }
    },
    changeCallback: function (event) {
        var max = this.$editor.next().attr("maxlength");
        if (typeof max !== "undefined" && max > 0) {
            var html = this.get();
            var current = html.length;
            var remaining = max - current;
            var $indicator = $(".indicator", this.$box);
            $(".current", $indicator).text(remaining);
            $(".max", $indicator).text(max);
            if (current >= max) {
                this.$box.css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
                $indicator.css("color", "#ff0000");
            } else {
                this.$box.css("border", "1px solid #DDDDDD");
                $indicator.css("color", "#000000");
            }                
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this was an old version of redactor, where `obj` was redactor's textarea element.

Note that the current redactor doc shows that there is only one parameter in keyupCallback, which is the event.

Comment: Thanks, MForMarlon: I've updated the code here to match our latest version.

Comment: One question: why do you need this: this.$editor.trigger("richTextEdited"); ? Thanks for sharing this peace of code.

Comment: @MEM - I should have taken that out before posting. That line is triggering a custom event called richTextEdited. We're listening for that in some other code that needs to know whether the form is 'dirty'. Unless you need to do the same you can ignore it!

Answer (score 1):

obj.$el is the jQuery element of the original textarea.

obj.$el.getCode().length gives you unexpected results as it takes into account the HTML elements being added.

I think a more accurate way to do this is to target the ".redactor_editor" to get the text length

New keupCallback method:

```
keyupCallback: function (obj) {
    var max = obj.$el.getEditor().next().attr("maxlength");
    if (typeof max !== "undefined") {
        var $box = obj.$el.closest(".redactor_box")
            ,current = $box.find('.redactor_editor').text().length
            ,$indicator = $(".indicator", $box);

        if ($indicator.size() === 0) {
            $box.append($("<div class='indicator' style='position:absolute;z-index:30;top:7px;right:7px;'><span class='current'>" + current + "</span> of <span class='max'>" + max + "</span></div>"));
        } else {
            $(".current", $indicator).text(current);
            $(".max", $indicator).text(max);
        }
        if (current >= max) {
            $box.css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
            $indicator.css("color", "#ff0000");
        } else {
            $box.css("border", "1px solid #DDDDDD");
            $indicator.css("color", "#000000");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I wanted to include the html characters as well as the text, as the character count relates to the maximum field size in the database - so good to have both versions, cheers!

Comment: This helped me a lot as well, because I actually need it to count the text chars, without any html tags. One small add on, in order to remove the extra ZERO WIDTH White Space added by redactor: `var editorWithCleanText = this.$editor.text().replace(/\u200B/g,'');` - `$editor.text` is your `('.redactor_editor').text()`. :)

Answer (score 0):

ok first you need to make sure that you have these 2 plugins in your redactor folder :

- [limiter](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/limiter/)
- [counter](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/counter/)

you need use limiter to limit the length, and counter to show the statusbar. The example code will look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redactor</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- redactor css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/your-folder/redactor.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- element -->
        <textarea id="content">...</textarea>

        <!-- redactor js -->
        <script src="/your-folder/redactor.js"></script>

        <!-- plugin js -->
        <script src="/your-folder/plugins/limiter.js"></script>
        <script src="/your-folder/plugins/counter.js"></script>

        <!-- call -->
        <script>
        $R('#content', {
            plugins: ['limiter', 'counter'],
            limiter: 100
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```